# Missing headers in Safari

Tags: javascript, node.js, safari, google-cloud-functions, http-headers

I have a few endpoints written in Node.JS hosted with Firebase Cloud Functions. When I run my app in safari, my backend is returning a response in some instances, and when I check I can see that they are returning with all of the correct headers in the request [image]

However, in some cases when I run my app in safari the backend returns no response and is missing numerous request headers.

[image]

Also getting these errors not too sure what to make of this

[image]

Comment: It seems that the status in Safari is not a "200 OK", but that in the first browser it is 200?  So it might be the lack of headers is from a failed handling of the request rather than the server giving back different headers based on the User Agent?

Comment: @GregFenton what if the same request is working in different browsers? When I run this app in chrome and firefox it responds fine with all of the headers

Comment: What version of Safari are you using?